# How to get IQueryable() instead of List() using LinQ?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, code-first, iqueryable

Data structure:

```
class Journal
{    
    public int JournalId {get; set;}
    public DateTime JournalDate {get; set;}
    public string OwnerId {get; set;}
}

class Event
{
    public string EventId {get; set;}
    public string EventName {get; set;}
}
```

Is there any way to get 
First of all I get that List of values

```
var events = DBContext.Events.Where(o => o.EventName.Contains(searchParam)).AsQueryable();
var values = events.Select(x => x.EventID).ToList();
```

I only know how to put query results to list in foreach cycle. I created new list put there all values where events in list of values I need

```
JournalList  = new List<Journal>();
foreach (string eventId in values)
{
   var results = DBContext.Journals.Where(j => j.eventID.Equals   (eventId)).ToList();
   RegJournalList.AddRange(results);
}

GroupedList = JournalList.Select(t => new JournalGrouped()
{
  JournalID = t.JournalID,
  JournalDate = t.JournalDate
}).Distinct().ToList();
```

Is there a way to have `IQueryable()` instead of `JournalList`?

Comment: List is IQueryable?

Comment: append a **.AsQueryable()**

Comment: I assume `j.eventID.Equals   (eventId)` is a typo and it should be `j.JournalId...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you look into `join`. It is basically what you are trying to do

```
var result = (from event in DBContext.Events
              where event.EventName.Contains(searchParam)
              join journal in DBContext.Journals on event.EventID equals journal.JournalID
              select new JournalGrouped()
              {
                JournalID = journal.JournalID,
                JournalDate = journal.JournalDate
              }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Or better still since you are using Entity Framework use **[navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx)** and let the framework do the work for you. After defining the navigation properties it will look something like:

```
from journal in DBContext.Journals.Include("full name of your Event class")
where journal.Event.EventName.Contains(searchParam)
select new JournalGrouped()
{
   JournalID = journal.JournalID,
   JournalDate = journal.JournalDate
}
```

If you for some reason what to stick with the way you currenly are doing it then:

```
var values = DBContext.Events.Where(o => o.EventName.Contains(searchParam))
                             .Select(x => x.EventID);

var GroupedList = DBContext.Journals.Where(j => values.Contain(j.eventID))
                                    .Select(t => new JournalGrouped()
                                    {
                                        JournalID = t.JournalID,
                                        JournalDate = t.JournalDate
                                    }).Distinct();
```

Comment: I am using navigation property and tried to write a query like You suggested, but it took so long (62 ms) I think it is too long for me, but it seems I have nothing to do .... And I need to have IQueryable, because I need to add more filters to Journals... not only by EventId :(

Comment: @Songaila - I suggest then that you check the sql that is generated and then execute it in the database itself to check its explain plan.

Comment: I got data I need, but a little bit long to wait... it is about 2.5 mil records in db, so think it woudn't take so long...

Comment: Ya... Does make sense that will take time. But check explain plan - see how joins are performed and maybe it can be improved. There is a stack exchange for DBAs and maybe you can do some pre-processing

Comment: @Songaila - please consider accepting my answer as it solves the problem described in the scope of the question :)